# Objective java using method from another class

Tags: java

I am new in objective programming and I need a litle help with using methods from another class.
I have method decreaseTemperature(int alpha); in java class named Reactor (It is just a simple command alpha -= 1) It should decrease temperature by 1 every fps....

Reactor reactor = new Reactor(); - I cant use this

[Relationship of classes](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy;dir:LR;/class/%5B%3C%3Cabstract%3E%3E;AbstractActor%5D%5E-%5BReactor%5D,%20%5B%3C%3Cabstract%3E%3E;AbstractActor%5D%5E-%5BCooler%5D,%20%5BCooler%5D-%3E%5BReactor%5D,%20%5BCooler%5D%5E-%5BSmartCooler%5D,%20%5BSmartCooler%5D-%3E%5BReactor%5D.svg)

```
public class Cooler extends AbstractActor{

private final Animation fanAnimation;

public Cooler(Reactor reactor){            //this must be like that
    fanAnimation = new Animation("resources/images/fan.png", 32, 32, 200);
    setAnimation(fanAnimation);
    fanAnimation.setPingPong(true);
}

@Override
public void act(){
    reactor.decreaseTemperature(1);         //Here is a problem (this does not work) 
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `act()` method doesn't have access to the `reactor` instance variable.  If you need to pass it in to the `Cooler` constructor, then you need to save it so that other methods in the class have access to it.  Try this:

```
private final Animation fanAnimation;
private Reactor reactor;

public Cooler(Reactor reactor){            //this must be like that
    this.reactor = reactor;  // save the passed in parameter
    fanAnimation = new Animation("resources/images/fan.png", 32, 32, 200);
    setAnimation(fanAnimation);
    fanAnimation.setPingPong(true);
}

@Override
public void act(){
    reactor.decreaseTemperature(1);  // this now refers to the private Reactor instance variable
}
```